# I'm trying to remove a row in Excel with C#, but it doesn't work

Tags: c#, excel

I'm working on an project, where you can add contacts to an Excel file. Now I'm trying to remove the contacts from the Excel file. To remove the contact I need to delete the row where the data of the contact is, but the code I've tried doesn't delete only the specific row, it clears every row.

```cs
public static void deleterow(string path, int sheetnumber, int row)
{
    _Application excel = new Application();

    Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);

    Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[sheetnumber];

    ws.Rows.EntireRow.Delete(row);
            
    wb.Save();
    wb.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
_Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);

Worksheet ws = (Worksheet) wb.Worksheets[sheetnumber];

Range rg = (Range) ws.Rows[row];
rg.EntireRow.Delete();

wb.Save();
wb.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Excel.Range`s and find needed one (or more) by provided value:

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

List<Excel.Range> rangesToDelete = new List<Excel.Range>();

foreach (Excel.Range range in worksheet.UsedRange)
    if (range.Value2 is string value && value == "SomeContact") // <-- Your contact name or other identifier
        rangesToDelete.Add(range);

foreach (Excel.Range rangeToDelete in rangesToDelete)
    rangeToDelete.EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
```

For example, if I specify *"Person2"*, I'll get this result (before deleting/after deleting):
[image]
[image]